# My frontend service running inside my docker container cant communicate with my backend service running inside another container

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask

I have a vite react app running inside a container "frontend" and a flask app (in which all CORS are allowed using `CORS(app)`)  running inside a container "backend", both of these container share a common network "foobar", when i start both of these container on the same network and open my frontend app in the browser it is not able to communicate with the flask app running on my the backend container. But I can communicate with the containerized backend service from inside the frontend container in a shell session. Both of my containerized services are running fine invidually and both services ofcourse works fine when I run then locally on my host machine without the use of containers.

my networks on docker:

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
42a5069ef178   bridge    bridge    local
2a6098f8d24f   foobar    bridge    local
7bd05fc44ccf   host      host      local
36d9c3a8d498   none      null      local
```

I'm running my containers using:-
`docker run --rm --name backend --network foobar -p 5000:5000 backend:1.0.0`
`docker run --rm --name frontend --network foobar -p 3000:3000 frontend:1.0.0`

When I open my frontend in chrome:

```
GET http://backend:5000/api/get-random-video-key net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Uncaught (in promise) Ee {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
Error fetching options Ee {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
GET http://backend:5000/api/options net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

These Api calls doesnt show up in my backend logs.

But the thing is I can communicate with the backend container manually from within the frontend container in a shell session:

```
# docker exec -it frontend /bin/bash
# curl http://backend:5000/api/get-random-video-key
{
    "key": "a37fb6e1-68e3-4b40-97cc-8f2824fb11c9"
}
```

Comment: I think your issue might be because you did not link the containers. 
As @Brian Thompson said, how should the container know what "backend" is?

try following:
```bash
docker run --rm --name frontend --network foobar -p 3000:3000 --link backend frontend:1.0.0
```

but beware this is legacy functionality and you should rather alias your network as described in the docker wiki: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/

Comment: The network is enough to let the containers communicate with each other. You don't need to link them and for a client-server connection it won't make any difference as the browser still won't be able to connect to `backend` by name

Answer (score 1):

##### Problem

Frontend containers can be tricky because they have the potential to access other containers in two ways:

1. Container to Container

This is what your network is setup for. If your frontend container makes a server-side request, then the request is originating from the container and going to another over your `foobar` network.

2. Browser to Container

This is what is actually happening for you. Your failing request is coming from the browser. The code is *served* by the frontend container, but the request doesn't come from it - it comes from the browser. The request is made *outside* for the `foobar` network, which has some implications.

##### Solution

The problem is that `backend:5000` isn't going to work outside of the network, since there's no dns to resolve `backend` to the correct place - this is part of what the network does for you; allowing you to target a container by name.

I believe you can simply use `localhost:5000` for client side (browser) requests.

One additional thing to consider is that if your frontend container doesn't make any server-side requests, you can remove the network, as it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Using localhost:5000 does work on my machine but the thing is I wanted to make (somewhat) portable setup for deployement on ec2 and pulling and running these 2 images on the ec2 instance doesnt work.

Comment: The url will need to be an environment variable of some kind then, and you'll use localhost for dev and the url to your backend container when hosted in ec2